# different logo for home page and another logo for others page

Tags: logo

I want to use different logo for my home page and another logo for others page in wordpress.what will be the changes in header file and css.Currently i am using terminus theme.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using condition in your header file like

```
if(is_front_page() || is_home())
{

   // PUT YOUR HOME PAGE LOGO HERE

}else{

  // PUT LOGO FOR INNER PAGES

}
```

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

This **CSS** only example works on the **Terminus** demo site on Themeforest. The only difference is that demo site didn't have a page ID.

You'll need to look up the page/post IDs for the pages/posts you want to have different logos anyway. Then replace the example ID class I have below with your ID class.

Here's how to get the [page/post ID](https://dev.to/marklchaves/changing-up-header-logos-26c5#page-post-id).

```
/** 
 * Hide the default logo. 
 *
 * For posts use .postid-1 format.
 */
.page-id-1 .logo img {
    display: none;
}

/** 
 * Drop in a different logo.
 *
 * The site link is respected.
 */
.page-id-1 .logo {
    background-image: url(https://balistreetphotographer.files.wordpress.com/2019/02/balistreetphotographer-logo-2-slashes-65.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
}
```

Obviously **change** the logo URL and logo dimensions to yours.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php if(is_front_page() || is_home()) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' )); ?>">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/images/logo.png" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>" class="logo-width" alt="logo">
                                    <?php else : ?>
                                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/images/white_logo.png" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>" class="logo-width" alt="white-logo">
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    </a>
```

Comment: Use the above condition in header.php file. hope it will helps